# Show link only if association is present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my application, a `Product` has many `subscriptions` with the subscriber be a `User`:

```
class User
  has_many :products
  has_many :subscriptions, :foreign_key => :subscriber_id
end

class Product
  belongs_to :store
  has_many :subscriptions, :as => :subscribable
end

class Subscription
  belongs_to :subscriber, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :subscribable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

How would I show the link block based on if the Product has a subscription or not?

```
<% if #@product.subscription.present? %> 
   <%= link_to "Unsubscribe", { :controller => "products", :action => "unsubscribe_product", :id => product.id }, :method => :delete %>
 <% else %>
   <%= link_to "Subscribe", { :controller => "products", :action => "subscribe_product", :id => product.id }, :method => :post %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'll suggest to use method within User class

```
class User
  def subscribed_for?(subscribable)
    subscriptions.where(:subscribable_id => subscribable.id, :subscribable_type => subscribable.type).any?
  end

end
```

and for view use

```
<% if current_user.subscribed_for?(product) %> 
   <%= link_to "Unsubscribe", { :controller => "products", :action => "unsubscribe_product", :id => product.id }, :method => :delete %>
 <% else %>
   <%= link_to "Subscribe", { :controller => "products", :action => "subscribe_product", :id => product.id }, :method => :post %>
<% end %>
```